# Laravel 5 save and update not working.

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

When I update a product, the data not are updated.

Follow code

**My Controller**

```
public function viewProduct( $name, $id )
{

    $product = $this->queryProducts()
                    ->where('produtos.id' , $id )
                    ->first();

    $product->count_view += 1;
    $product->save();
 }
```

**My Model**

```
<?php
namespace App;    
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Products extends Model
{ 

protected $guarded = ['id'];
protected $table = 'produtos';
const CREATED_AT = 'created';
const UPDATED_AT = 'modified';
protected $fillable = ['count_view', 'nome'];
```

If i use

```
dd( $product->save() )
```

my return is true and i tried use the method save() from other way

```
$product->save( ['count_view' => 77 ] )
```

and/or

```
$product->update( ['count_view' => 77 ] )
```

But no way works

Answer (score 0):

I discovered my mistake...

When I created the query to search the products I made a join with another table and for this reason he was not updating .

To resolve the query I said I to select only the product table and now save and update works!

```
private function queryProducts()
{   
   return Products::join('fornecedores', 'fornecedores.id', '=' ,'produtos.fornecedor_id')
                        ->where( 'fornecedores.ativo', 1 )
                        ->where( 'produtos.moderacao', 'P' )
                        ->where( 'produtos.ativo' , 1 )  
                        ->select( 'produtos.*')                          
                        ->limit( $this->_limitProducts );
}
```